# Get product sales reports from postgresql via graphql

Tags: javascript, postgresql, graphql

I have a very limited experience with databases (I'm currently learning postgres), which is why I'm asking here, what would be the "industry standard" way of doing / creating sales reports based on a timeframe, from a postgres db via graphQL?

Why via graphQL? Because, as I said above, I'm just learning databases and don't know yet how to properly do JOINs, views, and other advanced queries.

My setup on the GraphQL side is this: `Products -> CartItems -> Orders -> OrderItems`.

On `AddtoCart` each product item is transformed into a `CartItem`. Once the order is finished, the `Cart` and each `CartItem` will be saved in the database as an `Order` and as `OrderItem`.

In the database I have the following:

`Product` - table with all products that are for sale.

`CartItem` - table with products that are in the Cart.

`Order` - table with all sales, with foreign keys to each OrderItem.

`OrderItem` - table with sold products.

Until now I used to get the monthly sales for each product by doing two nested graphQL queries in the frontend: one query to get all products, and one nested query to get the `aggregate.count` for each product, filtering by product name, store and timeframe.

Finally the question is: should I do this query at the database level using SQL? Should I create another table `Sales` and populate it with data from the other tables? If yes, what would be a good starting point, and if no, how should I continue to do this with GraphQL in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that GraphQL and SQL are different tools operating at different levels. SQL is executed at the database level.
Thinking about performance I would run this at the database level with SQL. You could create a database view named Sales that build the reports you want and simply run a select statement on that view.
Since you already have an OrderItem table , this table is actually the product sold so your Sales view could fetch data
Of course, you will have to filter OrderItem from cancelled Order.
With that in place you could build a request that only query this view.
Here are some explanations:  I made the assumptions on your table as follow:

- OrderItem --> (id, quantity, unit_price, created_at, order_id);
- Order(id, ...).

As an example you could create the Sales view like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Sales AS 
    SELECT row_number() OVER () as id, 
           SUM(oi.quantity) as products,
           COUNT(o.id) as orders,
           to_char(oi.created_at, 'MM-YYYY') as SELL_DATE,
           SUM(oi.quantity*oi.unit_price) as amount 
    FROM OrderItem oi, Order o 
    WHERE oi.order_id=o.id 
    GROUP BY SELL_DATE
    ORDER BY SELL_DATE;
```

this line "row_number() OVER () as id" is here to generate id in case your API need an id column.
Once you have the view "Sales" in place, you can query using a simple select like this :

```
SELECT * FROM Sales;
```